# Move-ADObject errors upon taking CSV-file input

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

Hoping you can help!

Where I work, when we create a user, the object is put in "CN=>User's full name<,OU=Something1,OU=Something2,DC=SomethingElse,DC=local".

From there the user object needs to be moved into one of two subsequent OU's to the OU they are put in (Say OU=Region1 and OU=Region2).

So the user object's final 'destination' is: `OU=Region1,OU=Something1,OU=Something2,DC=SomethingElse,DC=local` or `OU=Region2,OU=Something1,OU=Something2,DC=SomethingElse,DC=local`

This is possible with the PowerShell cmdlet "Move-ADObject".
Type in `Move-ADObject -identity "CN=CannonicalName,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local" -targetpath "OU=Region1/2,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local"` (as you're probably all very well aware).

During the creation process we use a .csv file to enter in the details of the user we create - the details we enter in are as follows: `Name,SamAccountName,displayName,givenName,title,surname,initials,EmailAddress,UserPrincipalName,HomeDrive,HomeDirectory,Company,PostalCode,City,StreetAddress,OfficePhone,country`

What I want to do, is I want to make two .PS1 files in the same folder - one that will take the "Name" parameter from the CSV file (as the new user's name is already there) to the Region1 "sub"-OU, and one for the Region2 "sub"-OU - but when I create those files solely containing the following code, it fails:
`Import-CSV C:\Path\To\CSV\file.csv | Move-ADObject -identity "CN=$_.Name,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local" -targetpath "OU=Region1/2,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local"`

Is it so, that `Move-ADObject` can not take input from a CSV-file - or am I making a mistake (and if so - what is my mistake)?
I am an absolute less-than-beginner at PowerShell-scripting, hence I hope someone here can help.

For a screenshot showing version info as well as the error message I get, see http://i211.photobucket.com/albums/bb33/DKDexter999/SS_HostInfo_ErrorMsg.png

Comment: did it move one user correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found its easier to get the object then to move the object.  You need to pass an AD object to Move-ADObject when using the pipeline, or you can pass a completed identity.  So you'll retrieve the ADUser, then preform actions on it, i.e. pass it to Move-ADOject.

```
Import-CSV C:\Path\To\CSV\file.csv | ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Name | Move-ADObject -targetpath "OU=Region1/2,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local" }
```

If you can gaurentee that to can build the whole identity string on the fly, then you method could be possible.  The CSV would have to contain the identity string though, "CN=Test User,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local"

I can't seem to add a comment to the other answer, but I can explain why your having the string issue.  It has to do with $_ variable expansion within the quoted string.  You can see this demonstrated here.

```
PS C:\> Import-Csv .\test.csv | %{$_.name}
Test User
PS C:\> Import-Csv .\test.csv | %{"$_.name"}
@{Name=Test User; SamAccountName=TU; displayName=Test User}.name
PS C:\> Import-Csv .\test.csv | %{"$($_.name)"}
Test User
```

My test.csv file contains:

```
Name,SamAccountName,displayName
Test User,TU,Test User
```

The string expansion just parses the $_ within the string, using $( [variable] ) tells powershell to 
expand the variable within the string.

So using this should work

```
Import-CSV C:\Path\To\CSV\file.csv | %{ Move-ADObject -identity "CN=$($_.Name),OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local" -targetpath "OU=Region1/2,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local" }
```

Comment: How would I add the string to the CSV file? (As in, what, other than the string itself, should I write?)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to keep the identity string in that file, primarily because the string itself would contain commas.  Having some other process build the string as a field inside your input File.csv for the express purpose of pulling it back out so you can use a single pipe.  Lastly, your original question stated the fields inside input file, are you going to modify how this file gets built?

Comment: You are officially my new hero! :)
The edit you made to your answer works! :D

Answer (score 0):

thinking that you want to wrap the move-adobject within a %{}

Import-CSV C:\Path\To\CSV\file.csv | %{Move-ADObject -identity "CN=$_.Name,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local" -targetpath "OU=Region1/2,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,DC=Something,DC=local"
}

also not to sound mean, I hope that you have a test\dev enviro domain to dev\test these things in.

Comment: With a "%" and {} added on each end, the following error emerges:
`Move-ADObject : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=@{Name=Test User; SamAccountName=TU; displayName=Test User}.Name,OU=OrgaUnit3,OU=OrgaUnit2,OU=OrgaUnit1,DC=VMDomain1,DC=local' under: 'DC=VMDomain1,DC=local'. At line:1 char:49`

And yes, I do have a test environment (as well as a testuser on the actual system) - "VMDomain1" = VirtualMachineDomain :-P

And no, not at one point have I gotten the part with "$_.Name" to work - but if I enter the CN manually it does.

Comment: ok so doing the following Import-CSV C:\Path\To\CSV\file.csv | %{$_.name} what happens?  if it shows anything other then "Test user" then thats your problem.

Comment: It shows "Test User" - nothing more, nothing less. :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was getting the same error and forced my brain to double-check the "OU" path. I was certain it was right; until, I checked again and realized I left out an entire OU in the path for the target. Quick fix, make sure that you are providing the exact path where the object is being moved. Trust me, double-check your path. I wasted/spent 30min. un-needed, because my path was wrong.

Example:

I typed, "OU=_Staging,OU=CHA,OU=Delegated OUs,DC=,DC=,DC="

I had to add the missing "Workstations" OU, see below:

I then typed: "OU=_Staging,OU=Workstations,OU=CHA,OU=Delegated OUs,DC=,DC=,DC="

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I put brackets for the DC values, so it yanked my text. It doesn't matter, since my issue was with the OU names.